# Why does $\operatorname{{\bf Spec}}(\mathcal{O}_U) = U$ hold for open subsets $U \subseteq X$ of a scheme $X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why does $\operatorname{{\bf Spec}}(\mathcal{O}_U) = U$ hold for open subsets $U \subseteq Y$ of a scheme $Y$?

The construction of $\operatorname{{\bf Spec}}(\mathcal{A})$ for a sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{O}_Y$-algebras is introduced in Hartshorn II. Ex. 5.17.

I don't see why gluing the affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_V(U))$ for $V \subseteq U$ yields the open subscheme $U$ of $Y$.

How does one see that these open sets $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_V(U))$ can be considered as open subsets of $U$ (or at least of $Y$)? -- This should nearly answer the above question.

I hope someone can give me some useful insights, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim must be false, because the map $\mathbf{Spec}(\mathcal O_U) \to Y$ is affine but an open immersion $U \to Y$ is not affine in general, for instance $\mathbb A^2 \setminus \{\operatorname{pt}\} \to \mathbb A^2$ is not affine.

To be more precise, the claim is true if and only if the open immersion $U \to Y$ is affine.

Comment: Then the hint of Hartshorn in the exercise II Ex. 5.18. (c) where he states $V = {\bf \operatorname{Spec}}(\mathcal{O}_V)$ is wrong? Or does he assume anything that makes $U \rightarrow Y$ affine?

Comment: Indeed you can only follow his hint if $V \to Y$ is affine, but this should be enough, because it suffices to establish the ismorphism of those locally free sheaves on basis open sets and then glue them.

Comment: Apart from that, you get my answer and see that the claim is obviously false if $U$ is a non-affine open of $\operatorname{Spec} A$?

Comment: If we changed the original question, it is true for relative spec, right?

Comment: No. Relative Spec = Absolute Spec if $Y$ is affine. My answer already contains the necessary and sufficient condition.